# R: print line when column value matches value from other file

Tags: r

In R, I have a list of 11 dataframes named list1. Every dataframe has the same structure:

```
names    col2    col3 
name1   1       10
name2   2       22
name4   3       40
```

I have another dataframe called table1 looking like this

```
names    col4    col5
name1    ...     ...
name2    ...     ...
name3    ...     ...
```

Now I want to take a subset of my original 11 dataframes. For each dataframe I only want to print the lines where there is a match between the values in the 'names' column of the dataframe and the names column in table1. So in this case, my new dataframe should look like this

```
names    col2    col3
name1    1       10
name2    2       22
```

All new dataframe should be appended again in a list2. Could I work with lapply and a match function?

```
mylist2 <- lapply(mylist1, 
    function(...){
    match(...)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
required.list =  lapply(list1, function(x) subset(x, names %in% table1$names))
```